# Why does the Mozilla Developer Guide prefer if (ptr) over if (ptr != nsnull)?

Tags: c++, coding-style

In the [Mozilla Developer Style Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Developer_Guide/Coding_Style), under ***C/C++ Practices***, one can find,

> When testing a pointer, use (!myPtr) or (myPtr); don't use myPtr != nsnull or myPtr == nsnull.

Is there a reason behind this? Or is it just a convention?

Comment: It's called `C/C++`, isn't that enough?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I think `nsnull` is a macro. So it works under C too. Maybe I should remove C++ specific `nullptr` from the question.

Comment: Good style guides explain the reasons behind the choices. Even if the reasons are just "because that's how we roll" (which seems to be the case here).

Comment: Nope, they didn't give any. I bet on the single `=` mistake, though.

Comment: More characters = typos. Less characters = type conversion issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a reason behind this?

Corporate coding guidelines exist because, in a large corporation, there will usually be someone who values aesthetic consistency above other programming concerns. They will generate reams of pointless guidelines such as this one, with the spurious justification that consistency of irrelevant details makes the code more readable. If the corporate environment is sufficiently dysfunctional, these guidelines will be enshrined in an official policy document and imposed on all developers.

> Or is it just a convention?

In this case, it's certainly better not to use some unconventional symbol which might or might not evaluate to a null pointer value; although presumably `nsnull` is defined and mandated for that use by this style guide, and so the meaning would be clear to insiders. Whether `if (ptr)` is better than a more conventional `if (ptr != 0)` (or `NULL`, or `nullptr`) is a matter of taste: some will fight holy wars over their choice, others won't care.

Answer (score 2):

In general, company coding guidelines are just that - guidelines that are expected to be enforced inside that company.

This is a matter of preference - they both achieve the same thing (assuming `myPtr` is a pointer*), so it's purely subjective. For a large codebase, it's annoying seeing `if (myPtr)` in half the places and `if (myPtr != NULL)` in the other half.

<sub>*If `myPtr` is a non-pointer user-defined type, it can overload the operators `!`, `!=` and `==` so they may actually behave differently</sub>

Comment: I was hoping to gain some C++ insights (like one is more performant than the other), but it turns out to be just a convention.

Comment: @Hindol neither is faster. If you have a compiler where one is faster, ditch it for a better compiler.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility to commit a typographical error that would be very hard to find if you did this

```
if (myPtr = nsnull) /* assignment operator */
```

while you really meant this

```
if (myPtr == nsnull) /* test equality */
```

Comment: Any modern compiler will warn on this. This argument isn't valid for the last 10 years or so

Answer (score 0):

The style recommended by your style guide has a name: boolean zen. It's the essence of what a boolean expression is. Practicing boolean zen means to write boolean expressions in the simplest form possible. For example, this is not boolean zen:

```
bool foo() {
    if(myCondition()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Rewritten with boolean zen, you get this:

```
bool foo() {
    return myCondition();
}
```

I believe it's easy to see that the second is more desirable, simply because it does not add unnecessary code structure.

Now, in C derivatives, every integer/pointer has also a defined behavior if used in a boolean context. Doing that conversion by hand is pointless. I. e. in C/C++/Objective-C the if statements

```
bool foo = ...;
if(foo) printf("It's true");
if(foo != false) printf("It's really true");
```

are just as equivalent as the lines

```
Bar* foo = ...;
if(foo) printf("It exists");
if(foo != 0) printf("It really exists");
```

So, according to boolean zen, you should stick with the simpler one in either case.

---

You can find an introduction into boolean zen in this [slide-deck](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse142/08wi/lectures/2008-02-08%20ch05-3/14-ch05-3-boolean.pdf).